# Cadastro no formulário que se repete todo mês

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou desenvolvendo um app em Rails de controle de despesas e receitas pessoal. Eu queria que, no formulário, ao cadastrar uma despesa, o usuário marcasse um checkbox (consta na tabela de despesa como repeat:boolean) e então esta despesa se autocadastraria todo mês naquela mesma data. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

Eu nunca implementei algo deste tipo mas esta gem [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) parece ser bastante utilizada.

Link para artigo e video de como utilizar no [gorails](https://gorails.com/episodes/recurring-events)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar Active Job disponível no Rails.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html